# UIWebView Trigger Load more with Ajax website

Tags: ios, ajax, uiwebview

I am making an iOS APP which the data are coming from a website. I am on the way of figure out how to load more data when users scrolled the tableView to bottom.

**NOTE**： The UIWebView I created is in background so that I can get the content of what the webView is showing up in this hack way, but what users can only interact is a UITableView, however.

Cause the data my APP needs is where comes from a website(**Ajax**). I used this method to get the content of the website. Yes, I done this with `UIWebView` in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method.

```
NSString *htmlString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];
```

This works perfect and I got the content.

But the issue occurred as I had said before, when user scroll to bottom, the tableView need to load more data. So, my `UIWebView` also need to load more content for parsing more data from the content, so that the tableView can go ahead.  **Note: I am NOT in control of the pages on server**, So I could not get the API. (will cross-domain request possible?)

I had thought about these 2 methods:

**METHOD 1. Simulate a swipe up gesture to trigger *load more*** (When the webView scroll to bottom, the load more action will be triggered automatically)

**METHOD 2. Inject a javascript to tell `UIWebView` to load more data.**

I used Developer Tool within Chrome to catch the load more request.
Here are what I got.

```
Remote Address:54.165.215.138:443
Request URL:https://color.adobe.com/api/v2/themes?filter=public&startIndex=144&maxNumber=36&sort=like_count&time=week
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language:zh
accept-version:2.0.0
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:AMCV_9E1005A551ED61CA0A490D45@AdobeOrg=T; international=cn; storeregion=cn; __lc.visitor_id.1031448=S1421040023.3b40036efc; 57472748-VID=111520816012303; sfdc_session=-; mbox=PC#1422579254596-83420.19_07#1423794285|session#1422583820268-575696#1422586545|check#true#1422584745; kuler-loc=zh; cookies-enabled=1; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D35A9926601E31AD1-1D7E51664BFBD9C5%7C1485743101094%3B%20s_vs%3D1%7C1422586501096%3B%20gpv%3Dcolor.adobe.com%2520%253A%2520Explore%2520%253A%2520Most%2520Popular%2520%253A%2520Week%7C1422586501098%3B%20s_nr%3D1422584701102-Repeat%7C1454120701102%3B; s_sess=%20s_ppv%3D-%252C100%252C18%252C8054%3B%20s_cpc%3D0%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B; s_vi=[CS]v1|2A3C2EE20548B5C7-40000105000065EB[CE]; aam_uuid=33030698550757492143013270951098470183
Host:color.adobe.com
If-Modified-Since:Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Referer:https://color.adobe.com/zh/explore/most-popular/?time=week
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
x-api-key:7810788A1CFDC3A717C58F96BC4DD8B4
X-NewRelic-ID:UQAPV1JRGwEGV1RVBgQ=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
filter:public
startIndex:144
maxNumber:36
sort:like_count
time:week
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Content-Language, Date, Api-Version, Response-Time, X-API-Key
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Api-Version, Request-Id, Response-Time, X-API-Key
Api-Version:2.0.0
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:zh
Content-MD5:Hbz5uI3q/P2aEQ0+0TfZgg==
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' *.behance.net *.s2stagehance.com data: *.typekit.net *.adobe.com *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net; font-src 'self' data: *.typekit.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.typekit.net *.adobe.com adobe.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.services.adobe.com *.adobe.com *.adobetag.com *.typekit.net *.tt.omtrdc.net adobe.demdex.net *.newrelic.com *.adobelogin.com *.behance.net net.s2stagehance.com *.adobesunbreak.com; frame-src 'self' *.services.adobe.com *.adobelogin.com *.adobe.com adobe.com *.adobeku.com *.facebook.com *.adobe.demdex.net adobe.demdex.net; report-uri /api/v2/csp-reports; connect-src 'self' accounts.adobe.com www-stage.adobesunbreak.com *.services.adobe.com;
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 02:25:26 GMT
Expires:-1
Request-Id:4043bed0-a827-11e4-98a0-81fb44ac31c8
Response-Time:20
Server:kuler-prod
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31104000
transfer-encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

So I am wondering is there a way to trigger ***Load More*** in **UIWebView**. Is there any hack way to do that? If my question is not clear, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: The plural of datum is data, not datas. Data is acceptable for both singular and plural form.

Answer (score 1):

Determine in the HTML of the web page what javascript function is being called when you scroll to the bottom, then simply call that function using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, at which point the `UIWebView` will trigger that function. The downside however is that you won't be notified in any way when the new content has been loaded by AJAX, so you'll have to come up with another workaround for that.

Also, you mentioned:

> I am NOT in control of the pages on server

Which I read as:

> My app may break if the page changes

Why are you building your app around a web page which may change, rather than communicating with a documented API directly?

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on how the web page is loading more content (i.e. what's the JS call and how do they know when to call it). In general though, having your app rely on some website's content that you don't control is not a good idea. If they change their format your app will break and you'll need to submit an app update.

If you absolutely need the data from this website, then I would create your own wrapping web service that takes in the parameters you need (i.e. page number) and returns the data you want. The benefits of doing it this way are:

1. If the website changes formats, you can quickly deploy a service update without resubmitting your app.
2. Your old versions of the app will continue to work even if the website changes its format.